# How can I find out or record the X11 top-level window from which a top-level window was opened?

Tags: x11, window-managers, window-management

I'm thinking of writing an X11 window manager which does for windows something like what [TabKit](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5447/) does for tabs in Firefox (in its [default tree view mode](https://addons.mozilla.org/img/uploads/previews/full/15/15609.png?modified=1186078765)). To do this, I'd need to be to able to find out which window a window was opened from. Is there a standard way of finding this out?

(I've never done *any* X11 programming without using a cross-platform toolkit on top of X11, let alone writing a window manager.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the difficult cases - applications launching other applications, e.g. a word processor launching a web browser - there's going to be a need for co-operation between applications to track this information. The [Zeitgeist project](http://zeitgeist-project.com/) already seeks to track which documents were opened from which documents, which is close enough that I should probably work with Zeitgeist (and/or its KDE equivalent - Nepomuk?) to get this implemented.